# Why might JavaScript be encoded with hex characters?

Tags: javascript, hex

I'd like to ask if you've ever seen something like the following code.

```
var _0x655fx23 = _0x655fx2[_0x34ea[0]] > 8 ? 3 : 1;
var _0x655fx10 = new Array(32 * _0x655fx23);
var _0x655fx25 = new Array(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0);
var _0x655fx26, _0x655fx27, _0x655fx11 = 0,
    _0x655fx28 = 0,
    _0x655fx14;
```

All I know of this is that it's supposed to be JavaScript. First I tried to convert all hex chars to ascii, but the result was nonsense (not to mention I have 200+ lines of this).

After some reading I came across a possible solution: de-obfuscation, but that didn't work either. Might you happen to have any experience "decoding" such codes? I already tried a number of online tools to recover as much of the code as possible, but without any luck, unfortunately.

Comment: *"it's supposed to be JavaScript"* - If you read it again while bearing in mind that JS variable names are allowed to start with underscores you'd see that it is quite valid JS (although the first line references a couple of variables that aren't defined).

Comment: @nnnnnn so amm. If we take the first line for example ( _0x655fx23 ) : "_e_#" would be considered a valid variable name?

Comment: Where are you getting `_e_#` from? The variable name is `_0x655fx23`, that is, the variable name is the sequence of characters `_, x, 6, 5, 5, f, x, 2, 3`. It doesn't get interpreted as a hex number. (Just as `var id1` creates a variable name from the characters `i, d, 1`.)

Comment: Just awesome... Thanks for pointing it out :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no sorcery, just the context of the code is hidden because it has been converted to hex. The same way you could rename these as variable1, variable2, variable3 but the purpose of them is still obfuscated. 
I imagine it could be achieved with tools like grunt, similarly to minifying your code.